# An equation for derivation of gravitational waves polarization forms

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, gravitational-waves

[image]

When I was reading Spacetime and Geometry An Introduction to General Relativity by Sean Carroll(Page 297,Equation 7.110), I couldn't solve this problem in the proper way to get an approximation.
Equation is $$\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial t^{2}} S^{1}=\frac{1}{2} S^{1} \frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial t^{2}}\left(h_{+} e^{i k_{\sigma} x^{\sigma}}\right)$$
and the book said, "These can be immediately solved to yield, to lowest order:"
$$S^{1}=\left(1+\frac{1}{2} h_{+} e^{i k_{\sigma} x^{\sigma}}\right) S^{1}(0).$$

My ideal is rewrite this equation as
$$\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial t^{2}} S^{1}+\frac{1}{2} S^{1} \left(h_{+} k_0^2e^{i k_{\sigma} x^{\sigma}}\right)=0$$
and use series to expand the term:
$$h_{+} k_0^2e^{i k_{\sigma} x^{\sigma}}$$

But I still have some questions on how to expand this term by series due to solution above.

Comment: Welcome to Physics Stack Exchange! Sorry nobody welcomed you before. You somehow slipped under the radar. Please keep in mind that , if you appreciate an answer -like the ones that were given below - you should UPVOTE it, by clicking on the up arrow. If ,in addition, you find one answer to be the best and completely satisfy your curiosity, you should ACCEPT it, by clicking the checkmark. You can/should do both things for the best answer that you receive....

Comment: ...You are a smart person, but so are the people answering your questions. When they will see that you do not upvote anybody, they will have ZERO incentive to answer your questions. Ok? I upvoted your question because it was interesting and well posed. Again welcome to Physics Stack Exchange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment "These can be immediately solved to yield, to lowest order" should hint a much simpler solution is possible. Write $S^1=\color{red}{S^1(0)}(1+\delta)$ with $\delta\ll1$ so$$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}\color{red}{S^1(0)}(1+\delta)=\frac12\color{red}{S^1(0)}\color{orange}{(1+\delta)}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}(h_+\exp ik_\sigma x^\sigma).$$Cancel the red factors and neglect the orange one, viz.$$\frac{\partial^2\delta}{\partial t^2}=\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}\left(\frac12h_+\exp ik_\sigma x^\sigma\right)\implies\delta=A+Bt+\frac12h_+\exp ik_\sigma x^\sigma.$$Since $\delta\ll1$ for all $t$, $A=B=0$.

Comment: Thank you very much, your method inspired me much!

Answer (score 1):

I find a way to solve this problem by expanding the solution by series, suppose the solution can be written down as:
$$S^1(t) = \sum^{+\infty}_{n=0}a_n \exp(i nk_\sigma x^\sigma)$$
$a_n$are numbers, the equation can be rewrite as:
$$k_0^2\sum^{+\infty}_{n=1}n^2a_n\exp(ink_\sigma x^\sigma)=\frac{1}{2} h_{+}k_0^2\sum^{+\infty}_{n=0}a_n\exp(i(n+1)k_\sigma x^\sigma)$$
$$\sum^{+\infty}_{n=0}(n+1)^2a_{n+1}\exp(i(n+1)k_\sigma x^\sigma)=\frac{1}{2} h_{+}\sum^{+\infty}_{n=0}a_n\exp(i(n+1)k_\sigma x^\sigma) $$
Since the bases $\{\exp(int)\}$ are linear independent, we get:
$$a_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{a_n h_+}{(n+1)^2}$$
And in weak field, $|h_+|<<1$, we dropped higher order terms:
$$S^1(t) = a_0 + \frac{1}{2}a_0 h_+\exp(i k\sigma x^\sigma)$$
Use initial condition to get the $a_0 = S^1(0)$, thus we get the answer.

Comment: ....and also upvoted your own solution :-)